# How to get the first column/td value of a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, html-table, associative-array

I want to get the ID of a row which I want to use to generate the url.
I am generating the table rows using following code.

```
<?
    $sql="SELECT pID,pName,pBudget,pRate FROM projects ORDER BY id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $projects = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $projects[] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($projects as $row) 
        { 
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($row as $element)
            {
                echo "<td>".$element."</td>";               
            }
            echo "<td class=\"actions\">
                    <a href=\"project.php?pID=$element[0]\">
                    Go to Project
                    </a>
                </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

?>
```

All work fine except the last `<td>` of the row. (not sure I am using the correct wording.)
Let's say my database table row is

```
pID   |     pName      | pBudget | pRate
-----------------------------------------
12345 | Create Website | 250     | hourly
```

then I am getting the table rows like this in my page

```
<tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Create Website</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>hourly</td>
    <td><a href="project.php?pID=h">Got to project</a></td>
</tr>
```

Why the last `<td>` does not have the `pID` value '12345' and why there is 'h' ?
I want the last `<td>` to be:

```
<td><a href="project.php?pID=12345">Got to project</a></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the last  does not have the pID value '12345' and why there is 'h'?

Because value of `$element` after `foreach` loop is over is **hourly**. First symbol of this string is `h`.

Correct version is:

```
echo ".....<a href=\"project.php?pID={$row['pID']}\">
```

as you use `fetch_assoc` function.

Comment: ooh.., understood ..but i am getting just this now `<a href="project.php?pID=>`

Comment: still same.. I mean url has no ID and I am getting this in error log `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pId in ... functions.php on line 37` line 37 is `echo "<td class=\"actions\"><a href=\"project.php?pID={$row['pId']}\">go tot project</a>`

Comment: Sorry, `pID`, not `pId`. By the way you can print row and see what is there.

Comment: lol.. that's the mistake only genius people can make... thanks a lot.. it works fine now..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT pID,pName,pBudget,pRate FROM projects ORDER BY id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['pName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['pBudget']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['pRate']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='actions'>
                <a href='project.php?pID=$row['pID']'>
                Go to Project
                </a>
            </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```